# manpages fails to update

Tags: apt, debian, manpage

I run `apt-get update` and all the other packages update fine, but manpages fails with this error

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
  manpages
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,118 kB of archives.
After this operation, 273 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Reading changelogs... Done
(Reading database ... 237568 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../manpages_4.04-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking manpages (4.04-2) over (3.74-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/manpages_4.04-2_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man4/console.4.gz', which is also in package console-tools 2:0.2.3-73
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/manpages_4.04-2_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

output of `apt-cache policy manpages console-tools`:

```
manpages:
  Installed: 3.74-1
  Candidate: 4.04-2
  Version table:
     4.04-2 500
        500 http://http.us.debian.org/debian testing/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://http.us.debian.org/debian testing/main i386 Packages
 *** 3.74-1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
console-tools:
  Installed: 2:0.2.3-73
  Candidate: 2:0.2.3-73
  Version table:
 *** 2:0.2.3-73 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

how do I fix this?

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy manpages console-tools`? Please [edit] your question to add the output and then notify me with a comment.

Comment: added the output of apt-cache policy manpages console-tools

Comment: Are you really running Ubuntu? Why do you have the Debian Testing repository installed then? Please also add the output of `grep -r --include '*.list' '^deb ' /etc/apt`.

Comment: No, I'm on Debian (I indicated it by the debian tag), nonetheless the apt-get and packaging is the same as Ubuntu

Comment: The package console-tools was in conflict, I removed it (and installed kbd as replacement) and it resolved ok, thanks for the help!

Comment: But Debian is off-topic here. We only support Ubuntu and its official flavours. Although Debian has similar packages, they are not the same. You should have asked this on [unix.se] instead. It's definitely a Debian-specific question and not Ubuntu related.